# Unresolved dependency SBT, scalariform

Tags: scala, sbt, ivy, typesafe-stack, scalariform

I am receiving this compilation error:

```
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-scalariform;1.3.0: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]      com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-scalariform:1.3.0 (scalaVersion=2.11, sbtVersion=0.13)
[warn]
```

In the root of my project I have a **build.sbt** file:

```
   scalaVersion in ThisBuild := "2.11.6"
```

I also have a core/build.sbt file with several resolvers, libraryDependencies, and exclusions.

**project/plugins.sbt**:

```
   addSbtPlugin(...)
   resolvers += "Typesafe Public Repo" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases"
   resolvers += "JBoss Repository" at "http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public//"
```

**~/.sbt/0.13/global.sbt**

```
   scalaVersion := "2.11.6"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to remove `scalaVersion := "2.11.6"` from `~/.sbt/0.13/global.sbt`.

In sbt 0.13, sbt and its ecosystem of plugins is current using Scala 2.10.

Answer (score 1):

The sbt-scalariform changed the groupId/organization

- `1.3.0` - `"com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-scalariform" % "1.3.0"`

  - available only for scala 2.9.1, 2.9.2 and 2.10
  - sbt 0.13
  - as seen here: https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-scalariform/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/1.3.0/
- `1.4.0`, `1.5.0`, ... , `1.8.2` - `"org.scalariform" % "sbt-scalariform" & "1.8.2"`

  - https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scalariform/sbt-scalariform_2.10_0.13/
  - https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22sbt-scalariform%22